# AWS S3 - Access denied when restricting access to referer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, next.js, nextjs-image

I have a Next.js app, using the new next/image feature, getting 403-Access denied when attempting to access S3 objects with the following policy:

```
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "PublicRead",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:GetObjectVersion"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringLike": {
                "aws:Referer": [
                    "https://my-website.com/*",
                    "http://localhost:3000/*"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]
}
```

The `referer` is included in the request header as below, as required by S3's docs:

[image: dev tools network tab]

If I do remove the `Condition` from the above policy, it will give access to the image, but that is not what I am looking for.

I have seen related questions in SO and elsewhere by the way, but they do not address this specific issue.

Comment: It is strange to see `localhost` as a Referer. It's probably not the value that is seen by S3 when the request is received. By the way, using `Referer` is not very secure -- it is very easy to fake that value, so it should not be used to restrict access to any sensitive data.

Answer (score 3):

Recently I also started having this problem, starting with in Chrome, then Firefox as well (Edge still working). In search of a solution, I removed the `Condition` like you state, and it indeed worked.

After checking what could be wrong with the `referer` condition, it turned out that the format in which the referer is send has changed: instead of the format 'https://example.com/', I see the format 'https://example.com' for my HTTP requests (so without trailing forward slash). The referer send for localhost is 'http://null'.

Changing this in the bucket policy worked for me.

So for you, your condition should look like

```
        "Condition": {
        "StringLike": {
            "aws:Referer": [
                "https://my-website.com*",
                "http://null"
            ]
        }
    }
```